# Is there a programmable remote vibration motor?

Tags: motor, bluetooth, vibration

I am a developer and loves to develop all kind of things for me to simplify my life.
Now I'm looking for the possibility to wear a tiny device that receives signals from an app of mine to vibrate when some notifications come up. The transmission would be Bluetooth.

Is there such a device in form of a e.g. bracelet? When there isn't, what parts do I need to build one?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's called a "[smart watch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smartwatch)".

Comment: @dave-tweed +1 You made my day :D

Comment: @DaveTweed  Some exercise bands can fit the bill: FitBit (some of them have Bluetooth LE), Microsoft Band, and others.

Comment: +1 to the smartwatch. A pebble time costs about 120 USD (the first model is even cheaper), and there is an SDK that lets you develop your own apps for it if simple notifications are not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [Vibration Motor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8449). They can look like this:

[image: Vib Motor]

Besides this you will need some [bluetooth chip](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12574) to interface the motor and enable it to receive notifications from your mobile phone. Getting everything (motor + BT module + Battery + charging circuit) in a wearable form factor would be slightly difficult depending upon your expertise level.

Alternatively you can use commonly available smart watches which already have everything ready for you. you just need to program them accordingly.

Comment: lol 'slightly' +1